# Want to filter gcp docker image digest from container registry

Tags: bash, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I made a script which is filter the gcp docker container digest who is 25 days old, and the result will loop into gcloud docker container delete command. It's working, but my concern is if the latest one itself on 25 days older then my script will delete them also. I want to skip if there is only the latest one, it will skip to delete.

```
#!/bin/bash 
DIGESTS=$(gcloud container images list-tags ** --format 'value(digest)' --filter="timestamp.datetime < '$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="25 days ago")'")
COUNT=0 
echo "Keeping the latest 2 digest of the service" 
for DIGEST in $DIGESTS 
do 
((COUNT++)) 
if [[ $COUNT -gt 2 ]] ; 
then echo "Going to delete version $DIGEST of the zeus service." 
gcloud container images delete -q ***@sha256:$DIGEST 
else echo "Going to keep version $DIGEST of the name service." 
fi 
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add check of the number of containers and exit if it's only one

```
#!/bin/bash 
DIGESTS=$(gcloud container images list-tags ** --format 'value(digest)' --filter="timestamp.datetime < '$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="25 days ago")'")
WCOUNT=$(echo $DIGESTS|wc -w)
if [ "$WCOUNT" -eq 1 ]
 then exit
fi
echo "Keeping the latest 2 digest of the service" 
for DIGEST in $DIGESTS 
do 
if [[ $WCOUNT -gt 2 ]] ; 
then echo "Going to delete version $DIGEST of the zeus service." 
gcloud container images delete -q ***@sha256:$DIGEST 
else echo "Going to keep version $DIGEST of the name service." 
fi 
((WCOUNT--)) 
done
```

Comment: tried with your script but its not giving any response, just exited but there is 4 version which was 25 days old.

Comment: It depends of the exit from gcloud command. Will edit my answer to count words

Comment: I think WCOUNT is getting information only 1. But when I just ran the DIGESTS command in console, it returns 4 versions.

Comment: What return `echo $DIGESTS `? And now (with edited script this should work)

Comment: it returns the 4 versions.

Comment: yup almost thanks. am just change the `[[ $WCOUNT -gt 0 ]]` instead of `[[ $WCOUNT -gt 2 ]]`